# Rolling out "Quick Tools" Configuration for Adobe Acrobat DC

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I'm currently trying to roll out a pre-configured Quick Tools layout within Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. I'm hoping to be able to append an extra divider and "Add-on Tool" to the bar to save configuring it manually or requiring each user to set it up themselves.

I've tried overwriting UserPrefs_Acrobat to reflect this new layout by adding to "FavoritesCommandsDesktop" but Acrobat goes back and wipes out my changes.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort this one myself after a bit of digging.

In conjunction with the UserPrefs_Acrobat.txt file, I also had to make some changes in the Registry;

I added the "cFavoritesCommandsDesktop" key to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\DC\AVGeneral" and within that I placed 6 string values named "a0" through to "a5". The value for these strings reflects the tools/elements in the respective slots.

[image: registry values]